# F2 mesh script not filling to quad

Tags: mesh, scripting, add-on

Trying to use F2 mesh to make a quad but the original Fkey input seems to be interfering.

According to [this post](https://blenderartists.org/t/f2-plugin-error/666244), the script in the info tab should read `bpy.ops.mesh.f2()` if it's working and
`bpy.ops.mesh.edge_face_add()` if it doesn't. However, my info reads both of those like: `bpy.ops.mesh.edge_face_add()`
`bpy.ops.mesh.f2()`

Anyone know what's going on here? F2 to mesh just refuses to fill as a quad.

I've restarted my computer, restarted Blender, loaded factory save preferences, reinstalled blender itself all to the same result.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.